# "off of" vs. "off from"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Example of usage of *off from* in context:

> Compensatory time off for travel may be used by an employee when the employee is granted time **off from** his or her scheduled tour of duty established for leave purposes.

Example of usage of *off of* in context:

> Sarah Palin was nearly pulled **off of** Fox News because she announced that she was not running for president on a rival broadcaster.

Would it be okay to say instead that Sarah Palin was nearly pulled **off from** Fox News or that the employee is granted time **off of** his or her scheduled tour?

Are *off of* and *off from* interchangeable?

Comment: _Off of_ means the same as _off_ in contexts like this. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of) says it's more common in American English, but I've heard people from South-East England use it too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jump off of \ jump off the rock.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203205/jump-off-of-jump-off-the-rock) Also [What does "off of" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/what-does-off-of-mean) and ["On" vs. "Off of" vs. "Off"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93347/on-vs-off-of-vs-off), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers None of those address the "off from" part of my question.

Comment: In your context, ***off from*** illustrates almost exactly the same principle as ***off of = off***. The difference is that ***off from = off = from*** (i.e. - *either* of those prepositions can be used on its own in your *exact* context, but there may be other contexts where that's not quite true). Many, *many* prepositions in English can be "doubled up" like this without affecting the meaning, so we can't really have a separate question for each such permutation.

Comment: ... [Should there be only one preposition in the following sentence: from or on?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297841/should-there-be-only-one-preposition-in-the-following-sentence-from-or-on) specifically addresses ***off*** or ***off from***, but it's a slightly different context.

Comment: See [this AmE usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+time+off+from+work%2Ctake+time+off+work&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) showing that Americans still *slightly* prefer to "double up" in *time off from work*, but they're rapidly falling into line with [the British preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+time+off+from+work%2Ctake+time+off+work&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) (we swapped over to preferring the single preposition over 50 years ago).

Comment: I've had blazing rows on here before now over this… yet I will say again, 'off of' makes you sound uneducated. 'Off from' is a new one to me, yet feels the same. Just use 'off'.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - I think so too, but I have had to accept it's just my prejudice, after finding it in Samuel Pepys' diary, and also checking its history - The phrase has a long history, which, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, stretches back roughly 500 years. If you and I want to consider it to be "wrong", then we have to accept that it certainly has a lot of staying power.